# Getting the maximum value from an increasing range of cells in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, aggregate

In Excel I store items, and for each item I know how much I used and how much I got at a given time like this:

```
Item 1  10
Item 2  20
Item 2  -10
Item 2  5
Item 1  10
Item 1  -5
```

When the value is a positive number, I know that that's a gain, and when it's negative, then that's a loss.

With simply using `SUMIF`, I could know at the end that how much I have currently from a given item.

However I would like to know what was the maximum amount I ever had. In this example, that number would be 20 for Item 1 for example. I know I could just calculate the partial results in a different column for each item, then use `MAX` on those, but I would like to find a solution which solves this with one equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the newer [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) can use its cyclic processing to mimic a 'helper' column of `=SUMIFS(B$2:B2, A$2:A2, A2)`.

In F5 as a standard formula,

```
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, SUMIFS(OFFSET(B$2, 0, 0, ROW($1:$6), 1), OFFSET(A$2, 0, 0, ROW($1:$6), 1), E5), 1)
```

[image: aggregate_sumifs]

I do not usually proselytize the use of the [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) due to its inherent volatile² nature but reshaping the range to sum demands it.

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

² <sub>Volatile functions recalculate whenever anything in the entire workbook changes, not just when something that affects their outcome changes. Examples of **volatile** functions are [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd), [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592), [TODAY](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566), [NOW](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NOW-function-3337FD29-145A-4347-B2E6-20C904739C46), [RAND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RAND-function-4CBFA695-8869-4788-8D90-021EA9F5BE73) and [RANDBETWEEN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4CC7F0D1-87DC-4EB7-987F-A469AB381685). Some sub-functions of the [CELL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF) and [INFO](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INFO-function-725f259a-0e4b-49b3-8b52-58815c69acae) worksheet functions will make them volatile as well.</sub>

Comment: Note that I've changed a value for *Item 2* in order to more closely show a true calculation.

Comment: This is what I needed! I wasn't aware of this "new" function, and I'm glad that you've introduced me to it. However I would like to ask one question: I haven't saw `ROW` used in such a way. Could you, please, tell me how it's supposed to work? As I see it generates an array of numbers from 1 to 6. But doesn't it mean that I should use the whole equation as an array function? I experience no difference in the results if I put it into a {}, but I'm wondering.

Comment: The [ROW function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/ROW-function-3A63B74A-C4D0-4093-B49A-E76EB49A6D8D) in this context does not refer to a row on teh worksheet. It generates a sequential array of numbers; e.g. `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}`. This is used to reshape the SUMIFS range(s) as `B2:B2, B2:B3, ... B2:B7`. Some functions of AGGREGATE produce cyclic (aka *array*) calculations without CSE (like SUMPRODUCT), The **14** ([LARGE function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db)) is one of them.

Comment: Use the [Evaluate Formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) command to get a step-by-step breakdown of what is happening. Keep your ranges small (like your sample) or the results will be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a macro for your sheet with VBA code such as this:

```
Public itemMax As Integer

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Set itemMax = -1
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    If Not (Intersect(target, Range("B1:B100")) Is Nothing) Then
        If IsNumeric(target) Then
            If target > itemMax Then
                itemMax = target
                MsgBox ("New max is: " & CStr(itemMax))
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

In this example, I keep track of the "global max" in `itemMax` and check if any new item count being added is bigger than purposely-set low max. I assumed you're entering these values in manually, one by one, so YMMV.

Comment: If it can be reasonably assumed that your [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro will be modified so that `itemMax` is to be written on the worksheet somewhere, wouldn't it be prudent to inc;ude a line that disabled the [Application.EnableEvents property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821508.aspx) in order that the Worksheet_Change does not try to run on top of itself?